# How do I replace doors that are not standard sizes?

Tags: doors, door-frame

I have 12 doors in my apartment that need to be replaced. All of them are of non-standard sizes. My door frames are typically 6 cm too high for the standard doors available. The widths are all fine.

Can I stick a 6 cm height wooden plank at the bottom? I plan to paint the doors with primer and top coat. Should I be worried that the joint will show after the layers of paint? Are there any other fixes available? Alternatively, can I cut a larger door?

Comment: What type doors are these, pass through, bi-fold etc ?

Comment: Does "apartment" indicate one you rent or one you own? Usually, in a rental one doesn't do work like this - it's up to the landlord.

Comment: if you are getting 12 doors your likely to get a better price than you would for a single door .. different materials (including species of woods) grow / shrink at different rates, so even if you make a perfect join once it gets colder or hotter its possible you'll get a crack or visible join.

Comment: With that many I would look into putting new skins on the doors. Cheaper than new and cheaper than reframing to a standard size. on the rentals we regularly ended up re-skinning doors especially the non standard ones